# How to override Form.Show() method in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to override `Show()` method for form, but the c# does not let me do it. I want to do it to refresh listbox when I am going back to the previous window. I do not want to use observable collection etc.

```
 protected override void Show() {
            base.Show();
            list.Items.Clear();
            loadListItems();
        }
```

> 'Sklep.OknoProduktow.Show()': cannot override inherited member
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()' because it is not marked
>   virtual, abstract, or override

Comment: Why don't you just put that code into the `Shown` event handler method ?

Comment: @HansPassant Show is a method not an event

Comment: @TLama I cannot find OnShow just the OnShown?

Comment: Sorry, my (Delphi) bad. I meant to use `Shown` event if you want to load those items whenever the form is first shown.

Comment: are you showing the another window as a modal window from your main form ?

Comment: Why not do the Show in the constructor and then the rest of this after?  You can put those three lines in the constructor of the form and get the same results.  Change the base to this, or just remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not  use from activated event?

It'll help you. When your form activated, your listbox will refresh.

I think that you can not override the `show()` and this is why it did not solve your issue.

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  list.Items.Clear();
  loadListItems();
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You cannot override the Show method, but you can shadow it. Put this code in the class of the form:

```
public new void Show()
{
     //your code here

     //call the shadowed Show method on our form.       
     base.Show();

}
```

Comment: A new topic to learn for me, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

You need to distinguish *events* and *methods*.  Overriding an event is not possible if it is not declared virtual.  The Form.Shown event is not virtual, nor is it protected.

There is another mechanism in place for overriding event handling in Winforms.  Every event Xxxx has a corresponding protected method named OnXxxx.  The duty of the OnXxxx() method is to fire the Xxxx event, ultimately taken care of by the implementation in the base class.  In this case by Form.OnShown().

The value of doing it this way is that you have additional *choices* in the way you want to override the default handling of the event:

- You can call base.OnShown() first, then do whatever you want to customize the event.  This let's you override whatever a custom event handler might have done.  Common in an OnPaint event handler for example when you want to make sure whatever you paint is on top of whatever the base class or event handler painted.
- You can write your customized code, then call base.OnShown().  Achieves the opposite goal, a custom event handler can override whatever you did.  This is the normal way.
- You can write your customized code and *not* call base.OnShown().  This prevents event handlers from running at all.  Rare to do this but the selection you want to make when your customization is so extensive that a client code's event handler is likely to malfunction.
- You can write your customized code, *not* call base.OnShown() but still fire the Shown event.  Rare as well but you'd have to do this if the base implementation gets in the way.

So the most likely correct implementation of your method is:

```
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
        loadListItems();
        //Call the original OnShown.
        base.OnShown(e);
    }
```

Which uses the 2nd bullet, allowing an event handler to customize the list you loaded.

Trying not to confuse the larger issue, you are doing this wrong.  The list should be initialized in the form constructor.